# How do I test post axios in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

i'm trying to make a simple test for my form submit function with axios Post request but i'm getting a error

My function for submit my form

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
  const origin = window.location.origin;

  await axios.post(`${origin}/movies/api/resources`, data);

  window.location.replace('/movies/resources');
};
```

my Test

```
import CreateMovie from '../create.js';
import axios from 'axios';

describe('CreateMovie', () => {
  jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn());
  it('Should send data', async () => {
    const response = await CreateMovie.onSubmit('http://localhost:3000/movies/api/resources', 'post');
    
    expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(response).toEqual();
  });
});
```

i'm getting this error

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSE
```

and

```
 CreateMovie
    ✕ should call onSubmit (67 ms)

  ● CreateResource › should call onSubmit

    Network Error
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from "axios"

 jest.mock('axios', () => ({
    post: jest.fn()
}))


describe('CreateMovie', () => {
    let locationMock;

    beforeEach(() => {
        locationMock = jest.spyOn(window, 'window','get')
    })
    it('Should send data', async () => {
        let replaceMock = jest.fn()
        locationMock.mockImplementation(() => ({
            location: {
                replace: replaceMock,
                origin: "http://localhost"
            }
        }))

        await onSubmit('post');

        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://localhost/movies/api/resources', 'post');
        expect(replaceMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/movies/resources')
    });
});
```

if you wanna verify the `axios.post()` has called, you need to mocking this method first, and then you just verify this method has called with something that you wanna expect like code above.